# Notation for constant random variables?

Tags: random-variable, notation

Suppose $X$ is a random variable. Now, suppose I want to add a constant random variable to $X$. Should I denote the constant by a lower- or upper-case letter? So $X+A$ or $X+a$?

Comment: "Suppose $X$ is a normally distributed random variable." I am supposing, I am supposing, .... but what does `normal-distribution` have to do with this question? Do you think the answer might be different if $X$ were not a _normally_ distributed random variable but some other kind of random variable, e.g. a $\chi^2$ random variable?

Comment: Sorry, it just happened to be case when I was thinking about this. I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to think of it as first and foremost a random variable (that happens to be constant), best to use $A$.

If you want to think of it primarily as a constant, it may be better to use $a$.

If in doubt, use $A$ but it can be (at least arguably) legitimate to use either.